# I can't use @use in sass file in Create React App + node-sass setup

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

In my `src/styles/variables.scss` file, I have `$primary-color: #171b42;` defined.

I want to use this variable in my `src/components/LandingPage/LandingPage.module.scss` file.

Inside this file, I have:

```
@use "../../styles/variables.scss" as v;

$color: v.$primary-color;

.heading {
  color: $color;
}
```

I get this error:

`SassError: Invalid CSS after "$color: v": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$primary-color;"`

What am i doing wrong? I have `node-sass` installed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. If you pay close attention to the [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use), it says (as of 5/16/2020):

> Only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the @import rule instead.

Comment: For anyone searching where in the documentation it says that (like me): (currently) at the top of the page under "compatibility", there's a collapsed hidden part accessible via the triangle icon.

Answer (score 5):

I just installed 'sass' instead of 'node-sass' and it worked.

Comment: @NULLpointer just do 'npm i -D sass' . node-sass uses libsass and sass uses dartsass

Comment: You deserve to be the correct answer!!! It totally worked, wow.